# Accessing deeper object properties via string

Tags: php

I know this looks weird, but i need to access deeper object properties only when knowing the path from a string ("b->c") like you see below.

```
$a = new stdClass();
$a->b = new stdClass();

$a->b->c = "123";

$exp1 = "c";

$exp2 = "b->c";

print_r($a->b->$exp1); // works
print_r($a->$exp2);  // not so much
```

Any way to access the $a->b->c property when knowing only the object $a and having a string like "b->c" ?

Comment: But `print_r($a->{'b'}->{'c'});` will work

Comment: that way i need a string like "b_c" that gets exploded and then such a thing can be created. any way to do it just with a string when only having the $a object?

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with a short bit of code - this effectively splits it down into working one level at a time...

```
$a = new stdClass();
$a->b = new stdClass();

$a->b->c = "123";

$exp1 = "c";
$exp2 = "b->c";

print_r($a->b->$exp1); // works
print_r($a->$exp2);  // not so much
$val = $a;
foreach ( explode("->", $exp2) as $level )  {
    $val = $val->$level;
}
echo $val;
```

Outputs...

```
123PHP Notice:  Undefined property: stdClass::$b->c in /home/nigel/workspace/Architecture/test/test.php on line 18
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /home/nigel/workspace/Architecture/test/test.php:0
123
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative that avoids the use of `eval()` (tested in php 5.6):

```
<?php

function getNestedProperties($object, $path)
{
    foreach (explode('->', $path) as $property) {
        if (!isset($object->$property)) {
            return null;
        }
        $object = $object->$property;
    }
    return $object;
}
```

Running this:

```
$a = new stdClass();
$a->b = new stdClass();
$a->b->c = "123";
$exp2 = "b->c";
var_dump(getNestedProperties($a, $exp2));
```

Gives output:

```
string(3) "123"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`eval()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) and capture the output value to a variable.

```
$a = new stdClass();
$a->b = new stdClass();

$a->b->c = "123";

$exp1 = "c";

$exp2 = "b->c";

print_r($a->b->$exp1); // works
$out = '';
eval('$out = $a->'.$exp2.';');  // get value to $out with eval
print_r($out); // print it
```